# How to pass an URL object to material UI button without getting errors?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

In the [NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#with-url-object) I learned that we can use an URL object and it will get formatted automatically to create an URL string.

Functionally it works without problems, but the following error appears on the console:

`` Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `href` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(ButtonBase)`, expected `string`. ``

Here is a minimal CodeSandbox reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/next-materialui-objecturl-rmprr?file=/pages/index.js

```
// index.js
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Link from "../src/Link";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        component={Link}
        href={{
          pathname: "/about",
          query: { name: "test" }
        }}
        naked
        variant="contained"
      >
        Link button with url object
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// Link.js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import MuiLink from '@material-ui/core/Link';

const NextComposed = React.forwardRef(function NextComposed(props, ref) {
  const { as, href, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <NextLink href={href} as={as}>
      <a ref={ref} {...other} />
    </NextLink>
  );
});

NextComposed.propTypes = {
  as: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]),
  href: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]),
  prefetch: PropTypes.bool,
};

// A styled version of the Next.js Link component:
// https://nextjs.org/docs/#with-link
function Link(props) {
  const {
    href,
    activeClassName = 'active',
    className: classNameProps,
    innerRef,
    naked,
    ...other
  } = props;

  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = typeof href === 'string' ? href : href.pathname;
  const className = clsx(classNameProps, {
    [activeClassName]: router.pathname === pathname && activeClassName,
  });

  if (naked) {
    return <NextComposed className={className} ref={innerRef} href={href} {...other} />;
  }

  return (
    <MuiLink component={NextComposed} className={className} ref={innerRef} href={href} {...other} />
  );
}

Link.propTypes = {
  activeClassName: PropTypes.string,
  as: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]),
  className: PropTypes.string,
  href: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]),
  innerRef: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.object]),
  naked: PropTypes.bool,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  prefetch: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Link {...props} innerRef={ref} />);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24106) about this on the Material UI repository, a PR is going to be merge to provide a solution.

```js
// Link.js
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content */
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import MuiLink from '@material-ui/core/Link';

export const NextLinkComposed = React.forwardRef(function NextComposed(
  props,
  ref
) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
  const {
    href,
    to,
    as,
    replace,
    scroll,
    passHref,
    shallow,
    prefetch,
    ...other
  } = props;

  return (
    <NextLink href={to} as={as}>
      <a ref={ref} {...other} />
    </NextLink>
  );
});

NextLinkComposed.propTypes = {
  as: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]),
  prefetch: PropTypes.bool,
};

// A styled version of the Next.js Link component:
// https://nextjs.org/docs/#with-link
function Link(props) {
  const {
    href,
    activeClassName = 'active',
    className: classNameProps,
    innerRef,
    naked,
    ...other
  } = props;

  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = typeof href === 'string' ? href : href.pathname;
  const className = clsx(classNameProps, {
    [activeClassName]: router.pathname === pathname && activeClassName,
  });

  if (naked) {
    return (
      <NextLinkComposed
        className={className}
        ref={innerRef}
        to={href}
        {...other}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <MuiLink
      component={NextLinkComposed}
      className={className}
      ref={innerRef}
      to={href}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}

Link.propTypes = {
  activeClassName: PropTypes.string,
  as: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]),
  className: PropTypes.string,
  href: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]),
  innerRef: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.object]),
  naked: PropTypes.bool,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  prefetch: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Link {...props} innerRef={ref} />
));
```

The `Link.js` file is now exporting `NextLinkComposed` who can be use like this:

```js
// index.js
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { NextLinkComposed } from "../src/Link";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        component={NextLinkComposed}
        to={{
          pathname: "/about",
          query: { name: "test" }
        }}        
        variant="contained"
      >
        Link button with url object
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that `href` prop is renamed as `to` when using `NextLinkComposed`.